# Replacing dictionary keys for values in another dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries with information I'd like to replace under the keys of each dictionary.

So, I'm thinking of iterating through each dictionary and replacing the values.

I have another dictionary with the values I'd like to replace as keys and the values which should be the final ones as values.

It goes like this:

```
listOfDicts = [{'value_1' : 'A', 'value-2' : 'B', 'valu&_3' : 'C'}, {'value-1' : 'D', 'value_2' : 'E', 'value-3' : 'F'}, {'value_1' : 'G', 'value_2' : 'H', 'value_3' : 'I'}]
```

Then I have another dictionary to use as basis for fixing this information:

```
fixer = {'value-2' : 'value_2', 'value&_3' : 'value_3', 'value-3' : 'value_3', ...}
```

How could I make this replacement?

-
Edit:

The desired output would be somethink like this:

```
listOfDicts = [{
'value_1' : 'A',
'value_2' : 'B',
'value_3' : 'C'},
{'value_1' : 'D',
'value_2' : 'E',
'value_3' : 'F'},
...}
```

Comment: Can you show the expected output? Right now your text says you want to "*patch*" the values, but when looking at it, I somehow have the impression, you want ti fix the *keys*.

Comment: Did any of the answers work for you? If so, then make sure you accept the one that worked the best by pressed the tick mark next to the question.

Comment: Just did it, @WillemVanOnsem. Thank you! And the answers actually came a lot faster than I thought hey would, so I haven't tested them yet. I'm working on it right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
listOfDicts = [{'value_1' : 'A', 'value-2' : 'B', 'value&_3' : 'C'}, {'value-1' : 'D', 'value_2' : 'E', 'value-3' : 'F'}, {'value_1' : 'G', 'value_2' : 'H', 'value_3' : 'I'}]
fixer = {'value-1' : 'value_1', 'value-2' : 'value_2', 'value&_3' : 'value_3', 'value-3' : 'value_3'}

for i in range(len(listOfDicts)):

    keys = list(listOfDicts[i].keys())
    temp_dict = dict()

    for item in keys:
        if item in fixer:
            temp_dict[fixer[item]] = listOfDicts[i][item]

        else:
            temp_dict[item] = listOfDicts[i][item]

    listOfDicts[i] = temp_dict
print(listOfDicts)
```

**Output**

```
[{'value_1': 'A', 'value_2': 'B', 'value_3': 'C'}, {'value_1': 'D', 'value_2': 'E', 'value_3': 'F'}, {'value_1': 'G', 'value_2': 'H', 'value_3': 'I'}]
```

---

### Explanation

What this program does is that it iterates through each item in the list and gets the keys in the dictionary in the current item. It then creates a temporary dictionary (`temp_dict`), which will later store the fixed values in it. Then, the program goes through and sees whether or not any keys need to be fixed, and if so, it fixes the keys based on the `fixer` dictionary. Finally, it replaces the item being iterated in `listOfDicts` with the fixed values.

Answer (score 4):

We can fix every dictionary with a function:

```
fixer = {'value-2' : 'value_2', 'value&_3' : 'value_3', 'value-3' : 'value_3'}

def fix_dictionary(dict_):
    return { fixer.get(k, k): v for k, v in dict_.items() }
```

This will for a given `dict_` construct a new dictionary where keys that are in the `fixer` will be "fixed" (replaced by the corresponding value in the `fixer` dictionary).

We can then generate a new list of fixed dictionaries with:

```
[fix_dictionary(dict_) for dict_ in listOfDicts]
```

Or we can eliminate the function, and use a *one* liner:

```
[{ fixer.get(k, k): v for k, v in dict_.items() } for dict_ in listOfDicts]
```

Comment: For future reference: I tried this one as well and it worked

Comment: This seems the most elegant way to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If I've understood correctly you want something like this?

```
import json
import copy


listOfDicts = [
    {
        "valu&amp;_3": "C",
        "value-2": "B",
        "value_1": "A"
    },
    {
        "value-1": "D",
        "value-3": "F",
        "value_2": "E"
    },
    {
        "value_1": "G",
        "value_2": "H",
        "value_3": "I"
    }
]
fixer = {
    "valu&amp;_3": "value_3",
    "value-2": "value_2",
    "value-3": "value_3"
}

newDict = copy.deepcopy(listOfDicts)
for oldDct in newDict:
    for k2, v2 in fixer.items():
        value = oldDct.pop(k2, None)
        if value:
            oldDct[v2] = value

print('listOfDicts'.center(80, '-'))
print(json.dumps(listOfDicts, indent=4))
print('newDict'.center(80, '-'))
print(json.dumps(newDict, indent=4))
```

Output:

```
----------------------------------listOfDicts-----------------------------------
[
    {
        "valu&amp;_3": "C",
        "value-2": "B",
        "value_1": "A"
    },
    {
        "value-1": "D",
        "value-3": "F",
        "value_2": "E"
    },
    {
        "value_1": "G",
        "value_2": "H",
        "value_3": "I"
    }
]
------------------------------------newDict-------------------------------------
[
    {
        "value_1": "A",
        "value_3": "C",
        "value_2": "B"
    },
    {
        "value-1": "D",
        "value_2": "E",
        "value_3": "F"
    },
    {
        "value_1": "G",
        "value_2": "H",
        "value_3": "I"
    }
]
```